# Getting kth digit in a string concatenating all natural numbers

Tags: c++, string, math

I have an infinitely long string "12345678910111213141516171819202122232425..." which is a concatentation of every natural numbers in ascending order. I want to find the kth character in the string. However, my program is giving me incorrect output despite the logic being correct. I suspect an implementation bug somewhere

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    int T;
    cin >> T;
    while (T--) {
        int64_t k;
        cin >> k;
        int64_t aux = 9;
        int digit = 1;
        while (k > aux * digit) {
            k -= aux * digit;
            aux *= 10;
            digit++;
        }
        int64_t ans = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < digit - 1; i++) {
            ans *= 10;
        }
        ans += (k - 1) / digit - 1;
        k -= (k - 1) / digit * digit;
        int64_t helper = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < digit - k; i++) {
            helper *= 10;
        }
        cout << ans / helper % 10 << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
3
7
19
12
```

Expected Output:

```
7
4
1
```

My output

```
6
3
1
```

Comment: Well, did you try to debug your program?

Comment: Consider posting on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Quimby I. Didn't. I haven't learnt about. That yet..

Comment: @carcinogenicgame Fair enough, it is essential skill to learn though. See [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Depends on the IDE you are using, but all can do the basic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost correct but it seems that you do not have to minus 1 in `ans += (k - 1) / digit - 1`, changing it to `ans += (k - 1) / digit` should work.

Output:

```
7
4
1
```